# Pandas to_xml() setting xsi values

Tags: python, pandas, xml, xslt

I am trying to output to XML to meet a defined standard format so I cannot alter it. My current code:

```py
import pandas as pd

inp = {
    'EmployeeId': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Name': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'HJK', 'LMN', 'OPQ']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

print(df)

namespaces = {
    '': "",
    'xsi': "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    'xsd': "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
}

df['type'] = 'EmployeeDto'

df.to_xml('Test.xml',
          index=False,
          row_name='anyType',
          root_name='ArrayOfAnyType',
          namespaces=namespaces,
          encoding='utf-16',
          attr_cols=['type'],
          elem_cols=['EmployeeId', 'Name'])
```

Gives me this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>

<ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
  <anyType type="EmployeeDto">
    <EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
  </anyType>
  <anyType type="EmployeeDto">
    <EmployeeId>2</EmployeeId>
    <Name>DEF</Name>
  </anyType>
  <anyType type="EmployeeDto">
    <EmployeeId>3</EmployeeId>
    <Name>HJK</Name>
  </anyType>
  <anyType type="EmployeeDto">
    <EmployeeId>4</EmployeeId>
    <Name>LMN</Name>
  </anyType>
  <anyType type="EmployeeDto">
    <EmployeeId>5</EmployeeId>
    <Name>OPQ</Name>
  </anyType>
</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

Which is about as close as I have managed to get. I need to get it to look like this with the xsi: tag and I can't seem to add a namespace without having `"":""` in there which gives me a blank xmlns value...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

<ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <anyType xsi:type="EmployeeDto">
        <EmployeeId>114354</EmployeeId>
        <Name>Patrick</Name>
    </anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="EmployeeDto">
        <EmployeeId>114362</EmployeeId>
        <Name>Raymond</Name>
    </anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="BEmployeeDto">
        <EmployeeId>114364</EmployeeId>
        <Name>Paul</Name>
    </anyType>
</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace handling in `DataFrame.to_xml` mostly applies to root tag per [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html). For more in-depth design needs like namespaces in child nodes, consider using the `stylesheet` argument to run XSLT after original raw XML result.

Because you are using the default parser, `lxml`, you should be able to run XSLT 1.0 scripts. Note: XSLT can also be parsed from file like any XML document.

```py
...

mystyle = \
'''<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-16"/>
    
      <xsl:template match="ArrayOfAnyType">
        <ArrayOfAnyType 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">      
            <xsl:apply-templates select="anyType"/>
        </ArrayOfAnyType>
      </xsl:template>
  
      <xsl:template match="anyType">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:attribute name="xsi:type"><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="EmployeeId|Name"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>
  
      <xsl:template match="EmployeeId|Name">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>'''

df['type'] = 'EmployeeDto'

df.to_xml(
    r"Output.xml",
    index=False,
    row_name='anyType',
    root_name='ArrayOfAnyType',
    namespaces=namespaces,
    encoding='utf-16',
    attr_cols=['type'],
    elem_cols=['EmployeeId', 'Name'],
    pretty_print=True,
    stylesheet=mystyle
)
```

In fact, with XSLT, you can even cut down on the arguments of `to_xml`, defining new name nodes and which columns should render as elements or attributes:

```py
...

mystyle = \
'''<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-16"/>
  
      <xsl:template match="data">
        <ArrayOfAnyType 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
        </ArrayOfAnyType>
      </xsl:template>
  
      <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:element name="anyType">
          <xsl:attribute name="xsi:type"><xsl:value-of select="type"/></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="EmployeeId|Name"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>
  
      <xsl:template match="EmployeeId|Name">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>'''

df['type'] = 'EmployeeDto'

df.to_xml(
    "Output.xml",
    index=False,
    encoding='utf-16',
    stylesheet=mystyle
)
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Is it possible to expand on it so if I had a tag say: <Employee.Id> this would become a parent/child node like <Employee><Id>val</Id></Employee> ? I can control the delimiter so can set it to anything but would need it to do it to all tags that contain it.

Comment: Great to hear! That extension requires a more involved XSLT with string function like `substring-before` on the node name.